# Java Lambda expression: What is the meaning of id ->""

Tags: lambda, java-8

In a piece of Java code I inherited, I encountered the following what seems to be a Lambda expression:

```
id ->""
```

Appearing as a parameter to a method:

```
runner.setIntanceName(id ->"")
```

I consulted the [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) documentation but could not find the meaning of this special expression.

What does `id ->""` mean?

Comment: i.e `id` becomes `""`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. you have:

```
public static void setIntanceName(Function<String, String> function) {
    function.apply("aaa");
}
```

Then to use this method: `setIntanceName(id -> "")` or

```
setIntanceName(new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String id) {
        return "";
    }
});
```

I.e. you add a function to the method (or treat it as instance of some interface with only one method - it is called **functional interface**). Method `setIntanceName` will use this function. In given example, this function accepts `id=aaa` and returns always `empty` string as function's result.

Comment: To be clear, the lambda turns an empty string; it is not just an empty string in the body.

Comment: @MattSmeets you probably meant "**re**turns" and not "turns" :)

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand your answer correctly, all that `(id -> "")` means is: "Accept any string as a parameter but always return an empty string"?

Comment: Yes, simplified this code looks like runner.setInstanceName("")

Answer (score 1):

**The left side** specifies the parameters required by the expression, which could also be empty if no parameters are required.

**The right side** is the lambda body which specifies the actions of the lambda expression.

so here `id ->""` `id` is empty string.

read more about it [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-these-4-things-and-working-with-lambda-expressions-b0ab36e0fffc)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the parameter (left side) part. But what does an "empty string" **action** mean?

Comment: As you see in the answer its mean _specifies the actions_ such as any statement or expression. `id->id+1` or `id->"test"` or ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that person, who have written that intended to ignore any id-arguments and return just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`->` is just the token that separates the parameters from the body. See the part *Syntax of Lambda Expressions* in the very documentation you linked to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

`""` is the body. In this case, a constant empty string.